# using the Application object error

Tags: android

i am following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) tutorial, i have called the activity from the button when I click the button application crashes.

and my app manifest look like this:

```
<application
    android:name="com.krs.tell.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Activity with SearchDialog enabled -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.krs.tell.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Enabling Search Dialog -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>
   <activity android:name="com.krs.tell.feed.MainShopActivity" /> 
   </application>
```

I got this error below:

```
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start       activity ComponentInfo{com.krs.tell/com.krs.tell.feed.MainShopActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at com.krs.tell.feed.MainShopActivity.onCreate(MainShopActivity.java:53)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
 07-01 09:21:29.044: E/AndroidRuntime(4977):    ... 11 more
 07-01 09:21:29.049: E/EmbeddedLogger(508): App crashed! Process: com.krs.tell
 07-01 09:21:29.049: E/EmbeddedLogger(508): App crashed! Package: com.krs.tell v1 (1.0)
 07-01 09:21:29.049: E/EmbeddedLogger(508): Application Label: KRS
 07-01 09:21:29.049: W/ActivityManager(508):   Force finishing activity com.krs.tell/.feed.MainShopActivity
```

this is line 53 on MainShopActivity.class

```
 getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
```

my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="Content">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ChromeStylePopup" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">340dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#808080</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: You are using an object that is not initialized. MainShopActivity.java:53 in the line 53. Pless post your code for review it.

Comment: please post the relevant code of Your MainShopActivity

Comment: Pless edit this question and paste relevant code.

Comment: Post your `styles.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `parent` in your `AppBaseTheme style`

If you are targeting Honeycomb devices and higher you can use

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

or if you want to target lower API devices use

```
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

along with `android-support-v7-appcompat` as a support library for your project.

Comment: Thanks Apoorv for your help, but unfortunately its doesn't work

Comment: Are you hiding your `ActionBar` in any way?